# creating a entity relationship with user (jhiUser) in Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liquibase, jhipster

I have two entities "user" which is already created by jhipster and "car" the car have Many-to-one(bidirectional) relation with user

my queries are :

1> when I type `yo jhipster:entity user` it is creating new user entity rather then updating existing one I have also tried  `yo jhipster:entity jhiUser`

2> Where to use what ? either to use "user" or "jhiUser" and where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal you cannot create an entity which already exists especially User which is used for access control and basically this is what you tried by running `yo jhipster:entity user`.

You can't do bi-directional relations with user using entity sub generator, you could create many-to-one relation from car to user and then modify User manually.

Alternatively you could create a one-to-one relation between User and another entity CarOwner which would have a bi-directional one-to-many relationship with Car.

There are many questions about relations with User that you could search in stackoverflow.